# Substituir parte de uma String em Java

Tags: java

Tenho Strings que se repetem, apenas mudando uma palavra. Tenho um `case` para montar o conteúdo de e-mail, mas não quero ficar repetindo a string toda, sendo que o único valor que vai ser diferente, é se é front-end, back-end, mobile, etc.

Como faço isso da melhor maneira? Pra ficar um código mais clean?

```
String mailContent = "";
        switch (mail) {
        case "FRONTEND":
            mailContent = "Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador front-end, entraremos em contato.";
            break;

        case "BACKEND":
            mailContent = "Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador back-end, entraremos em contato.";
            break;

        case "MOBILE":
            mailContent = "Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador mobile, entraremos em contato.";
            break;

        case "GENERIC":
            mailContent = "Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador, entraremos em contato.";
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Não basta fazer um `if` e um `toLowerCase()` ?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a classe/método "String.format()", que lhe permite reutilizar a string, passando as variáveis que deseja substituir.

```
String cargo = "FRONTEND";
String mailContent = String.format("Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador %s, entraremos em contato.", cargo.toLowerCase());
System.out.println(mailContent );
```

**Saída**

> *Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador frontend, entraremos em contato.*

Isso pode ser interessante: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um HashMap para armazenar todas as profissões e usar o método já citado para criar a String desejada. Como segue no exemplo abaixo:

```
Map<String, String> occupations = new HashMap<String, String>();

occupations.put("FRONTEND", new String("programador front-end"));
occupations.put("BACKEND", new String("programador back-end"));
occupations.put("MOBILE", new String("programador mobile"));
occupations.put("GENERIC", new String("programador"));

String profession = occupations.get("MOBILE");

String mailContent = String.format("Assim que tivermos oportunidade para %s, entraremos em contato.", profession);
System.out.println(mailContent);
```

Exemplo completo: https://ideone.com/VpmbyF

Dessa forma o código fica bem mais fácil de dá manuntenção, pois evita que você tenha que fazer uma estrutura de controle enorme. Assim caso você precise adicionar uma nova profissão, somente precisará fazer um novo **put** em seu **HashMap**.

Answer (score 1):

As respostas anteriores são boas, mas vou deixar uma possível solução também:

Você pode usar a classe `StringBuilder`, que serve justamente para trabalhar com Strings dinâmicas.

```
StringBuilder mailContent = new StringBuilder();
mailContent.append("Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador");

switch (mail) {
case "FRONTEND":
    mailContent.append(" front-end");
    break;
case "BACKEND":
    mailContent.append(" back-end");
    break;
case "MOBILE":
    mailContent.append(" mobile");
    break;
}

mailContent.append(", entraremos em contato.");

return mailContent.toString();
```

Repare que para transformar o valor de uma `StringBuilder` em uma `String` "pura", basta chamar o método `toString()`.

Além disso, o código pode ficar um pouco mais simples uma vez que a classe `StringBuilder` tem um construtor que recebe um [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) como parâmetro (a classe `String` implementa a interface `CharSequence`):

```
StringBuilder mailContent = new StringBuilder("Assim que tivermos oportunidade para programador");

switch (mail) {
case "FRONTEND":
    mailContent.append(" front-end");
    break;
case "BACKEND":
    mailContent.append(" back-end");
    break;
case "MOBILE":
    mailContent.append(" mobile");
    break;
}

mailContent.append(", entraremos em contato.");

return mailContent.toString();
```

---

[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)